# FluentNHibernate AutoMapping : ClassConvention Does not work

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, conventions, automapping

I have a model library that I want to automatically build its NHibernate mappings using FluentNhibernate.
There's a convention that I'd like to add to this model and that is each table name ends with 's'.
So here's what I do :

```
new AutoPersistenceModel()
            .AddEntityAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly)
            .Conventions.Add(typeof(ClassConvention))
            .WriteMappingsTo(@"E:\Temp\");
```

Here's the code of ClassConvention :

```
private class ClassConvention:IClassConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name+"s");
        }
    }
```

but it simply doesn't work.No table attribute is added to class tag when I run this code.
Please help me understand what's wrong with my code ?

**Update:**

I have debugged my code and I am sure that this line :

```
instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name+"s");
```

is called.

Comment: which version Fluent NHibernate do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your convention defining class should be public not private

Comment: Right :) but this is a typo.